# sqlite or mysql for symfony2 CMF

Tags: symfony, pdo, symfony-cmf

I was installing the symfony2 CMF using composer and I noticed that the default PDO handler for it is set to sqlite. I'm just curious if there's any reason behind it that related to performance or the symfony team just don't feel like using mysql for CMF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the cmf sandbox is using sqlite only because this is the most simple thing to setup. for a production system with jackalope-doctrine-dbal, i would rather use mysql or postgres.

if you want optimal performance, your best option is jackalope-jackrabbit and installing the jackrabbit java server. for a production environment, you should install jackrabbit with tomcat. there is a tutorial in the jackalope wiki: https://github.com/jackalope/jackalope/wiki/Running-jackrabbit-in-tomcat-with-mysql

Answer (score 4):

And if you still prefer MySql, use the defaults but change 
 `database_driver: pdo_mysql 

database_path: null`

Comment: `database_driver: pdo_mysql` would be updated in `app/config/config.yml` and `database_path: null` would be updated in `app/config/parameters.yml`.